# PyGame parachute Error

Tags: python, pygame

Привет начал изучать PyGame и сразу столкнулся с ошибкой, а именно:
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault

Использую pygame 2.0.2 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 2.7.16), macOs

С помощью принтов определил что ошибка вылезает именно после инициализации

```
print ('import pygame')
import pygame
print ('import sys')
import sys
 
def run():
    print ('initiate pygame')
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("SpaceGame")
    bg_color = (0, 0, 0)
 
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
 
        screen.fill(bg_color)
        pygame.display.flip()
 
run()
```

Comment: (Информация из https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/429u21/fatal_python_error_pygame_parachute_segmentation/cz9jfzo/) Попробуй обновить python. Может помочт загрузка pygame для другой архитектуры процессора http://python-gaming.com/pygame/downloads.html. P.S. хмм, ссылка не работает, поищи на pypi.org(?)

Answer (score 0):

попробуй на пайтон 3 (желательно 3.8 или 3.10), потому что у меня всё работает

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос